# update the database in my controller with symfony

Tags: symfony5

how to UPDATE in a symfony controller
i got the userid and a name from a query parameter now i want if this information is retrieved well then change the value of 'etat' to 1,  i tried with that but it doesn't work
"'

```
/**
        * @Route("/acceptation", name="acceptation")
        */

        public function acceptation(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em, ValidatorInterface $validator):Response
        {
            $idU = $request->get('idUtilisateur');
            $nom= $request->get('nomTontine');

            $participant = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Participants::class)->findOneBy(['idUtilisateur'=> $idU , 'nomTontine'=> $nom]) ;            
            if( $participant)
            {
                
                $part= new Participants();
                $part->setEtat(1);
                $em -> persist($participant);
                    $em->flush();
                    
            }
            return $this->render('sunutontine/acceptation.html.twig' ,[
                'controller_name' => 'SunuController',
                ]);
    }
```

'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will do update an existing entity so do not instantiate new object.

persist, also is not obligatory when edit

```
if( $participant)
{
              
   $participant->setEtat(1);
  
   $em->flush();
                
}
```

Comment: Merci hous pour votre réponse ça marche,